# block diagonal matrix

Tags: r, matrix, symmetric

Suppose I have a list `Z` consisting of many matrices and I want to construct a block diagonal matrix from it.
ex :

```
[[1]]
             [,1]        [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 1.002500e+00 0.001930454 1.388794e-11
[2,] 1.930454e-03 1.002500000 1.930454e-03
[3,] 1.388794e-11 0.001930454 1.002500e+00

[[2]]
             [,1]        [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 1.002500e+00 0.001930454 1.388794e-11
[2,] 1.930454e-03 1.002500000 1.930454e-03
[3,] 1.388794e-11 0.001930454 1.002500e+00
```

I want to create a block diagonal matrix , I am currently using

```
block = bdiag(z)
```

However the `bdiag` command is slow when the number of matrices in the list is large. What is a fast and easy way to construct a block diagonal matrix from the list?

Note my matrix is also symmetric and every matrix in the list has similar dimensions.

Comment: how big is the list?

Comment: @rawr About 200 matrices each 25*25

Comment: I tried with 100,000 3x3 matrices, and it took less than a minute. a list of 200 25x25 matrices, eg,  `l <- rep(list(matrix(1:625, 25)), 200); x <- Matrix::bdiag(l)` finishes almost instantly

Comment: @rawr my application requires optimization of a function which involves bdiag() thus if my bdiag takes 1second then my optimization will take a huge amount of time. i am trying to squeeze the code as much as possible.

Comment: it *might* be possible to do this faster by indexing into a sparse matrix, but it seems very unlikely that the `bdiag()` step is really the limiting factor ... ?

Comment: Hi, if you have only dense matrices, it might be worth to have a look at the examples to Matrix::bdiag() . There is a function called bdiag_m() , which is the fastest solution I"ve seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to do a faster function, `bdiag2`.

```
library(Matrix)

bdiag2 <- function(Ms){
  l <- length(Ms)
  N <- nrow(Ms[[1]])  
  i0 <- rep(1:N, times=N:1)
  s <- rep(seq(0,(l-1)*N,by=N),each=length(i0))
  i <- rep(i0,l) + s
  j0 <- 1:N -> j
  for(k in 1:N){
    j0 <- j0[-1]
    j <- c(j, j0)
  }
  j <- rep(j,l) + s
  idx <- t(upper.tri(Ms[[1]], diag = TRUE))
  x <- unlist(lapply(Ms, "[", idx))
  sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x, symmetric = TRUE)
}

# test & benchmark
N <- 5; l <- 200
Ms <- replicate(l, toeplitz(1:N), simplify = FALSE)

stopifnot(all(bdiag(Ms) == bdiag2(Ms)))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  bdiag = bdiag(Ms),
  bdiag2 = bdiag2(Ms)
)


> microbenchmark(
+   bdiag = bdiag(Ms),
+   bdiag2 = bdiag2(Ms)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  bdiag 25.68078 27.393898 29.710474 28.566398 30.265242 54.393319   100   b
 bdiag2  1.34185  1.476838  1.693573  1.558724  1.769127  4.482054   100  a
```